# TSpeedButton background transparency problems with TVirtualImageList

Tags: delphi, vcl

If I load a BMP image into a `TSpeedButton.Glyph`, its background will be transparent. If I use the same button and image via a `TImageCollection` + `TVirtualImageList` pair, the background will be opaque. How can I make it transparent in this case as well?
I think this may be related to the resizing of the image and the averaging and blending of the colors. To be honest, this contradicts the fact that when the BMP is loaded into the `TImageCollection`, it is already displayed with a colored background. It is the same with a PNG image.

I use Delphi 11.1.5.

Comment: Do the PNG images really have a transparent background? Up to now I didn't encounter any problems with transparent PNGs in TImageCollection. I don't use BMPs anymore for quite some time.

Comment: @UweRaabe I just created a BMP/PNG with paint. How can I set the BG color in a PNG? The Glyph woks fine with BMP, as well.

Comment: Bitmaps can take a special color as transparent, but TImageCollection doesn't support that. Either the BMP or PNG have to provide real transparency in itself. I don't know how to do that in Paint.

Comment: @UweRaabe I tried online BG editors but I could not set a transparent color what works in TImageCollecion. What SW do you use to create a pic with transparent BG?

Comment: SnagIt: https://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.html

Comment: @SOLIDDevelopper Paint.net https://www.getpaint.net/

Comment: @DelphiCoder This is the 1st SW I can make an image BG color transparent by use it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: For decades [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) was an open source software supporting this already. There are [many more raster graphics editors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_raster_graphics_editors) out there...

Comment: Not sure where your problem is, but the _Image Collection Editor_ has a _Save as_ button  for that.

Comment: @DelphiCoder OK, but I don't want to save them by hand. I have more then 800 images in the project.